# Click Once Build Different Between Visual Studio and msbuild

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, msbuild, blazor, webview2

I am working on a Click Once Deployment Application. I can produce a working build by using the publish menu inside Visual Studio 2022. When I build the application outside of the Visual Studio using MSBuild it successfully installs but fails to launch. The goal is to in turn build that application with Azure DevOps Pipelines.

This is the what I run with MSBuild

```
msbuild CompanyPortal.Desktop.csproj -t:publish -p:PublishDir="C:/Users/rebel/Desktop/CompanyPortalBuild" /p:PublishProfile=ClickOnceProfile
```

Here is my publish profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationRevision>3</ApplicationRevision>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.*</ApplicationVersion>
    <BootstrapperEnabled>True</BootstrapperEnabled>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <CreateWebPageOnPublish>False</CreateWebPageOnPublish>
    <GenerateManifests>True</GenerateManifests>
    <Install>True</Install>
    <InstallFrom>Disk</InstallFrom>
    <IsRevisionIncremented>True</IsRevisionIncremented>
    <IsWebBootstrapper>False</IsWebBootstrapper>
    <ManifestCertificateThumbprint>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</ManifestCertificateThumbprint>
    <ManifestKeyFile>CompanyPortal.Desktop_TemporaryKey.pfx</ManifestKeyFile>
    <MapFileExtensions>True</MapFileExtensions>
    <OpenBrowserOnPublish>False</OpenBrowserOnPublish>
    <Platform>Any CPU</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishUrl>bin\publish\</PublishUrl>
    <PublishProtocol>ClickOnce</PublishProtocol>
    <PublishReadyToRun>False</PublishReadyToRun>
    <PublishSingleFile>False</PublishSingleFile>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>True</SelfContained>
    <SignatureAlgorithm>sha256RSA</SignatureAlgorithm>
    <SignManifests>False</SignManifests>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <UpdateEnabled>False</UpdateEnabled>
    <UpdateMode>Foreground</UpdateMode>
    <UpdateRequired>False</UpdateRequired>
    <WebPageFileName>Publish.html</WebPageFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Below is the csproj of the program I am trying to build and deploy using ClickOnce. This is a WPF using WebView to Display a Blazor wasm application

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
    <IsShippingPackage>false</IsShippingPackage>
    <AssemblyVersion>2.9.96</AssemblyVersion>
    <FileVersion>2.9.96</FileVersion>
    <Version>2.9.96</Version>
    <ApplicationIcon>wwwroot\favicon.ico</ApplicationIcon>
    <PackageIcon>Company_Portal_Icon_512.png</PackageIcon>
    <ApplicationManifest>app.manifest</ApplicationManifest>
      <RuntimeIdentifier>win-x86</RuntimeIdentifier>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebView.Wpf" Version="6.0.101-preview.11.2349" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\CompanyPortal.Components\CompanyPortal.Components.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Update="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="Company_Portal_Icon_512.png">
      <Pack>True</Pack>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Is there something I am missing? That would cause the build to work perfectly when it's built from Visual Studio but not from MSBuild?

Comment: Are you running the published app on your dev. machine or another?

Comment: I have tried both and neither work from msbuild. The test machine I used was a fresh AWS machine.

Comment: Is WebView2 runtime installed? try searching for: 'WebView2Loader.dll' in the installation folder.

Comment: Yes, the WebView2 loader is installed.